# IPv6 SQL to Perl

Tags: mysql, perl, ipv6

I have a field in a mysql table as a varbinary(16), which stores binary IPv6 addresses.

While toying around with my code and testing stuff, I filled one of its records with the binary value for:

```
0fff0fff0fff0fff0fff0fff0fe00000
```

(this is the value I see in phpmyadmin)

When I call up the value with the query:

```
SELECT INET6_NTOA(value)
FROM table
```

The return value I get is

```
fff:fff:fff:fff:fff:fff:fe0::
```

In perl, when I try to put this into a Net::IP-object:

```
$ip = new Net::IP('fff:fff:fff:fff:fff:fff:fe0::', 6);
```

It returns undefined.

My questions:

- Who or what is wrong here?
- Why?
- What can I do to make perl understand the IP address I'm giving to it?

Comment: Try again with real IPv6 addresses first

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently MySQL and `Net::IP` do not agree on the use of `::` to represent a trailing `:0`.

As far as I understand [RFC4191](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4291#section-2.2), `fff:fff:fff:fff:fff:fff:fe0::` should be a perfectly valid IPv6 address (expanded as `0fff:0fff:0fff:0fff:0fff:0fff:0fe0:0000`), but `Net::IP` does not seem to agree.

`Net::IP` seems to agree on using `::` for a trailing `:0:0`, but not for just `:0`. It is also OK with `::` replacing a single `:0:` anywhere else. Looks like a bug. It can be traced down to `ip_is_ipv6` which thinks that an IPv6 address cannot have 8 `:`s (which is true in all cases but a single leading or trailing 0 replaced by `::`).

You could do a bit of preprocessing to replace a trailing `::` with `:0` and a leading `::` with `0:` if there are 8 colons in the IP.

#### EDIT

It turns out that [RFC5952](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5952#section-4.2.2) says that single `0` (and hence a trailing `:0`) should not be replaced by `::` in output, so the MySQL `INET6_NTOA` is at fault, but it still says that RFC4191-compliant addresses should be accepted as input, so `Net::IP` should accept it nonetheless. Fixing the bug on either side would address the issue.

Comment: Actually, `fff:fff:fff:fff:fff:fff:fe0::` is a reserved address which should not be used for anything, possibly why it returns undefined. My guess is that this is a mangled link local address for something like `fe80:0:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff`, which would be a valid link-local address.

Comment: @RonMaupin, this happens also for `2001:0db8:85a3:0000:0000:8a2e:0370::`, and I have checked that the point it's rejected by `Net::IP` is when it finds there are 8 `:`s. Also, it is perfectly happy with the exact same IP address with a trailing `:0` instead of `::`.

Comment: The rules are that you do not replace a single word with `::`. RFC 5952 clarifies that in `2001:0db8:85a3:0000:0000:8a2e:0370::`, you must compress it as `2001:db8:85a3::8a2e:370:0`. Leading zeros are to be removed within words, and the longest string of zero words must be compressed (leftmost if there are two equal length sets of zero words), but not a single zero word.

Comment: Then the bug is in MySQL, not `Net::IP`. Let me change the answer.

Comment: Well, reading RFC 5952 in detail, it states that such representations should not be output (so MySQL is at fault), but also that they should be accepted as input if compliant with RFC 4191 (so `Net::IP` is at fault)!

Comment: I wrote my IPv6 routines so that just about any IPv6 representation is accepted, including IPv4 mixed, it is then converted to a 128-bit binary representation internally for manipulation, and anything output is in the RFC 5952 canonical format.